# parsing data from a web server

Tags: python

I am new to python and am just wondering what the best way to parse data from a webserver is.
I've googled and haven't found any decent tutorials, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your problem parsing the data, or getting the data? I'd think parsing data from a webserver is just like parsing any other data, once you have it. Or, is there a specific something you are trying to parse? What is it?

Comment: Your question is too vague to give a sensible answer.  Based on what you have said, look at the libraries Requests and BeautifulSoup.

Comment: -1 asking the most frequently asked question on Stackoverflow once again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use, [`BeatifulSoap`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Beautiful Soup is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and XML files. It works with your favorite parser to provide idiomatic ways of navigating, searching, and modifying the parse tree. It commonly saves programmers hours or days of work.

[Documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Example usage:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://facebook.com').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()
for anchor in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
   print anchor['href']
```

Comment: +1 to mention BeautifulSoup. Smart choice.